# React redux - how to pass state to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, state, reducers

I'm new to React and Redux. I'm trying to create a feature that lets you choose between two teams (onPress) then display the next view/component (which would be  hidden by default).

I created:

- index.ios.js - contains the store
- bet-view.js - the actual component
- pickPartyActions - I define some actions
- pickPartyReducers - I specify how the state changes

The reducer returns the new state correctly. I would like to use that new state and its properties to perform the next actions.

First - how can I use/pass of the new state (and its properties) from the reducer to another view or component?

```
<View>
  <Text>Set Bet Amount</Text>
</View>
```

Second - how can I hide that view and only show/display it after the onPress action?

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import BetView from './app/components/bet-view'
import reducers from './app/reducers/'

const store = createStore(reducers)
export default store

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState())
})

class testProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS 
        initialRoute={{
          component: BetView,
          title: 'Bet view',
          index: 0
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testProject', () => testProject);
```

**Bet view**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native'

import store from '../../index.ios'

import pickPartyActions from '../actions/pickPartyActions'
import pickPartyReducer from '../reducers/pickPartyReducer'

const BetView = ({navigator, parties}) =>
<View>
    <Text>{parties[0]} vs {parties[1]}</Text>
    <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => store.dispatch(pickPartyActions(partyType='left', name=parties[0], status='active', left='active', right='inactive'))}>
            <Text>Left</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => store.dispatch(pickPartyActions(partyType='right', name=parties[1], status='active', left='inactive', right='active'))}>
            <Text>Right</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>

    <View> 
        <Text>Set Bet Amount</Text>
    </View>
</View>

export default BetView
```

**Actions**

```
const pickPartyActions = (partyType, name, status, left, right) => {
    switch (partyType) {
        case 'left': {
            return {
                type: 'PICK_LEFT_PARTY',
                name,
                status,
                left,
                right,
            }
        }
        case 'right': {
            return {
                type: 'PICK_RIGHT_PARTY',
                name,
                status,
                left,
                right,
            }
        }
    }
}

export default pickPartyActions
```

**Reducer**

```
import pickPartyActions from '../actions/pickPartyActions'

const initialState = {
    name: '',
    status: 'inactive',
    left: 'inactive',
    right: 'inactive',
}

const pickPartyReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'PICK_LEFT_PARTY': {
            return {
                ...state,
                name: action.name,
                status: action.status,
                left: action.left,
                right: action.right,
            }
        }
        case 'PICK_RIGHT_PARTY': {
            return {
                ...state,
                name: action.name,
                status: action.status,
                left: action.left,
                right: action.right,
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default pickPartyReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, if I understood correctly, you are talking about passing information from the redux state to your components, to achieve that the best way read about connet and Provider of react-redux.
You can find everything in here :
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#api.

As for the second question, I think the best approach is to use react-router, the default oltion would be to render a component without the view, and the onPress change the route which will cause your other component to be rendered, and if you want to hide it, change the route again.
You can read more here:https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/README.md

However since youre using redux you should use react-rouer-redux:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hi @Pachu that's correct, I'm talking about passing information from redux state to my component. In this example the component is the other view on that same page (Bet view page) but ideally it will have its own file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Question 1:
use `connect` function as follows to pass the current state to component */
const mapStateToProps = function(state){
 
};
connect(mapStateToProps)(View); /* components that needs the state and access it from props */
/*
Question 2:
This needs to managed with a different props/state eg:
*/

{props.hasPressedButton?
  <View> 
        <Text>Set Bet Amount</Text>
  </View> : null 
}
```

Comment: Hi Jineesh, thanks for you response. It's a lot more clear  now.